# access modifier that makes classes in the same folder "friends"

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a access modifier (like public, private, etc) that makes all classes in the same namespace (in the same folder) friends?

Example:

```
namespace MYPROJ.As {
public class A {
    _______ A() {....}
}
}

namespace MYPROJ.As {
public class B {
    public DoSomething() {
        new A();   //I WANT THIS TO WORK
    }
}
}

namespace MYPROJ.Cs {
public class C {
    public DoSomething() {
        new A();   //I DON'T WANT THIS TO WORK
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT**

I want only B to be able instanciate A. How cam I do that?

Comment: Surely you are looking for the *internal* keyword?  Trust the people you work with, not the ones that use your assembly.  .NET doesn't have a workaround for not trusting your co-workers.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I don't see this as a matter of trust but more like constraint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "folder" you really mean "namespace" - no. None of the .NET access modifiers are related to namespaces at all.

Basically what controls accessibility is:

- Being within the same class (private access)
- Being nested within another class (private access to the containing class)
- Being in the same assembly (internal access)
- Being in another assembly with access via `InternalsVisibleTo` (internal access)
- Being a subclass of another class (protected access to the base class members, within slightly more complicated rules)
- Anything else (public access)

There's also `protected internal`, but I can never remember which way round that works, and I almost never use it :)

So if you can put class C into a different *assembly* to A and B (which are in the same assembly as each other), then you can make the constructor to A `internal` and get the result you want.

Comment: `protected internal` is both protected *and* internal visibility; there's nothing fancy, just the union of both concepts.

Comment: @dlev: So it's *less* restrictive than either? That's what I can never remember...

Comment: that's my understanding at least.

Comment: It's more like *or*. External derived types have access, and internal types have access. So in Assembly ABC, class B can access class A's `protected internal` members. In Assembly DEF, class C can inherit from class A and access the `protected internal` member.

Comment: @Anthony Yeah, I was using "and" to mean "either will apply"; I suppose "or" makes more sense there. That's also what I meant by "union" rather than "intersection".

Comment: @dlev, and sure enough, I used "and" in my own description. Tricksy modifiers.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: In case I cannot put C in other assembly, and I want A to be known everywhere but A's constructor to be known only by B, what is my best option?

Comment: @Naor: You could nest B inside A. That's the only choice really, if everything's got to be in the same assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Internal is what you're looking for

Comment: I want only B to be able instanciate A. How cam I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite, but there's [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), which limits access to classes within the same assembly (i.e. project).

Comment: I want only B to be able instanciate A. How cam I do that?